Why is GNU GLIBC strsignal() considered thread unsafe on modern operating systems?
Background
First of all, I know the general reason strsignal() is not threading safe is the standard says it may not be.
The strsignal() GNU C standard library function is defined in the POSIX.1-2008 specification, and in that specification it says:

The strsignal() function need not be thread-safe.

Link to specification https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/functions/strsignal.html
Since the standard does not require strsignal() to be thread safe, code using this function
can not assume it is thread safe, unless the specific implementation being used were to specify it was thread safe.
For example the POSIX.1-2008 spec says that strerror() may not be thread safe, but a change in glibc 2.32 means that in newer versions of glibc this function is now thread safe, and is listed as such on man 3 strerror.
https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2020-08/msg00002.html
Question
The manual page for the GNU linux version of the C standard library function for strsignal() specifies that this function is thread unsafe:
Linux man-pages 6.7
man 3 strsignal
┌───────────────────────────────┬───────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ Interface                     │ Attribute     │ Value                           │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ strsignal()                   │ Thread safety │ MT-Unsafe race:strsignal locale │
├───────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ sigdescr_np(), sigabbrev_np() │ Thread safety │ MT-Safe                         │
└───────────────────────────────┴───────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘

However, a peek at the source code reveals that specifically for glibc shows that since 2.32 strsignal() has uses a thread local buffer, which I would think makes it thread safe.
https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.32/source/string/strsignal.c#L27
So, as of glibc 2.32, why is strerror() considered MT-Safe, but strsignal() is still
documented here as MT-Unsafe?
The source code also reveals that there are no locale specific bindings for strsignal(), despite the documentation saying there is a possible locale thread race. Is this future proofing for changes that may be made in the future?
Update
The GLIBC commit that changed this behavior specifically says the change was made because the prior code was not thread safe.
https://github.com/bminor/glibc/commit/9deec7c8bab24659e78172dd850f4ca37c57940c#diff-0b727c8213dd076266c94142830b355d2ae281b0c7e246847a8558783ec6e242

To be clear "The strsignal() C standard library function is defined in the POSIX specification, ..." --> strsignal() is not in the  C standard library.  Perhaps better as ""The strsignal()  function is defined in the POSIX specification, ...".  Maybe a link to that specification.

C language does not know anything about signals. Sop how can it be part of the standard library?

Possibly the documentation is out of sync with the code

@chux @0 Clarified question, as you are correct the ISO C spec does not include the strsignal() function. By C standard library, I was referring to glibc, the GNU C standard library. (Note that ISO C does specify the existence of signals https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf)

@0___________: Re “C language does not know anything about signals. Sop how can it be part of the standard library?”: Signals are in the C standard, and signal facilities are specified in C 2018 clause 7.14, “Signal handling <signal.h>”.

First, you need to realize that GLIBC and man-pages are completely separate projects.
The documentation may be incorrect or stale (patches welcome).
Second, the fact that strsignal is using thread-local buffer does not itself guarantee thread-safety. Everything strsignal calls must also be thread-safe.
The "race on locale" comment implies that

the output is affected by locale
which isn't thread-safe (involves global variables)


Can you elaborate on how GLIBC and man-pages are separate projects? I thought the man pages came directly from glibc. No?

@TheMatt No. GLIBC documentation that is part of the GLIBC project comes in the form of info pages. The man pages is a completely separate project.
